# Is it possible to prevent systemd from executing the command specified with ExecStop?

Tags: systemd, services

I have a service that I only need systemd to run `ExecStart=` command at boot, and don't run the `ExecStop` action at shutdown / reboot.

Is that possible?

I can't just remove the `ExecStop` line, 'cause sometimes I need to shutdown the service manually. A live example is apparmor service, you need to activate all profiles on start, but no need to disable any of them at system shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ExecStop` to a wrapper script which first detects the conditions (like being in the shotdown process) under which you (don't) want the real stop code be executed and then either calls the real `ExecStop` entry or just aborts.

Comment: How to detect the shutdown event?

Comment: @warl0ck E.g. with the output of `runlevel`.

Comment: runlevel works for systemd? Mine returns `unknown` ...

Comment: @warl0ck There is a `systemd` version for `runlevel` which is installed here and works... Maybe you should make that a separate question. Probably the "runlevel" change is logged somewhere (`dmesg`?). Maybe this info can be taken from other `systemd` commands (`systemctl list-jobs`?).